# How does the C++ compiler find operator overloading?

Tags: c++

I have been looking into examples of operator overloading and some will include code snippets such as

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt)
{
    os << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;
    return os;
}
```

The `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, ...)` seems to placed, for what atleast seems "randomly" around a C++ program. My question is, can it be placed anywhere? How does the C++ find, compile and now interpret overloading `<<` for the class `Date` to now return a `ostream&` and use this function.

Comment: Just like anything in your program, there needs to be a declaration _somewhere_ prior to the overload being used.  And at link time, this needs to resolve to an actual definition somewhere.  Perhaps an _appropriate_ place to put this would be wherever `Date` is defined.

Comment: An overloaded operator is just a function with a funny name. It should be placed exactly like any other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply define as an inline as you did

```
std::ostream& operator << ( ostream& os, const Date& dt ) {
    os << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;
    return os;
}
```

But you have to include this header before you use it, otherwise the C++ compiler will not know.

Or you can define as a friend inline inside the class, which will allow you to tap into private and protected fields, for example if the "mo", "da" and "yr" fields were private inside Date.

```
class Date { 
...
    friend inline std::ostream& operator << ( ostream& os, const Date& dt ) {
        os << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;
        return os;
    }
};
```

or you can define in the header (Date.h)

```
class Date { 
...
    friend std::ostream& operator << ( ostream& os, const Date& dt );
};
```

and then implement in the body (Date.cpp) file

```
std::ostream& operator << ( ostream& os, const Date& dt ) {
    os << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very sort answer could be the ***scope*** of the `operator` function defines the places where it will be effective.

How to control the *scope* of a function/method is out of the scope of this question. (pun intended)

Answer (score 1):

This is ADL, argument-dependent-lookup, see e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

For example, typically all the standard `operator<<(std::ostream&, ...)` are defined in `std::` namespace, they don't exist in global namespace. So, why does code like `std::cout << "Hi there";` work, where the operator is not explicitly namepaced?

Only with ADL the compiler will search and find them in `std`, because of the location of `cout / ostream / etc` in the namespace `std`. Thus, when you write new operators, make sure ADL will find them -- without polluting the global namespace.

This is true for all function name lookups, operator overloading is just a special case for this.